# Jquery .on() is not working

Tags: jquery

I am  adding the element dynamically to a div tag. After that i want to perform click event on this newly added element. But its not working.

Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login-option').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/login_form.pl",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            //expect html to be returned
            // script call was *not* successful
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('div#proper-form').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);

                alert("script error");
            },
            // error 

            // script call was successful 
            success: function (response) {
                $("div#proper-form").html('<b id="testid"> testing</b>');
            }
        });

        $('div#proper-form').fadeIn(5000);
        return false;
    });

    $('div#proper-form').on('click', '#testid', function () {
        alert("working as expected");
    });
});
```

New element is added, but click is not working on it. Can please help me in finding what is wrong here.

Any help will be great help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Try using .live instead of .on

Comment: live is no more alive buddy!!

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

Comment: The code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5F3K/ something else must be interfering

Comment: @KOALA, YOU was right. I was adding 2 different versions of jquery lib. that's why it was not working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Please note the below code and test it

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login-option').click(function () {

    $.ajax( {
        url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/login_form.pl",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned

        // script call was *not* successful
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
          $('div#proper-form').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText 
            + ", textStatus: " + textStatus 
            + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);

          alert ("script error");


        }, // error 


        // script call was successful 

        success : function(response)
        {
            $("div#proper-form").html('<b id="testid"> testing</b>' ); 
            $('#testid').bind('click', function () {
               alert ("working as expected"); 
            });
        }
    });


    $('div#proper-form').fadeIn(5000);
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Prashant. Your code is working fine. Thanks for the help. Do you have any idea why .on() is not working??

Comment: Yes, When you call and asynchronous call, it will not wait for the return status. Compiler will execute the next line after your $.ajax({}); line, i.e your $(..).on('click',...); line.
Which executes before your code binds the new element in your success: function() {..}.
Hence, it needs to be return inside the success callback.

Do mark it as answer, so that it can be helpful for other user in future. if stuck with same issue.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal actually what would be of help to future users is that you note that the actual issue was the inclusion of 2 versions of jquery since the code in the OP was correct and using `on()` is actually the preferred way of attaching event handlers since version 1.7. Personally I would suggest you answer your own question with that fact instead of accepting this one.

Comment: @koala_dev: I haven't mention that on() is creating the issue. I have mentioned about the server time to execute the asynchronous call back, the on() method as per the code in the question executes before the New Tag was Inserted. Hence we have to write that code inside the Success Call back function. Yes, you are true for using bind() and on(), we should opt for on(), but the actual issue was not in the versioning but the asynchronous call back. The jsfiddle you mention is without asynchronous call back. Hope you understand the problem now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    $('#testid').bind('click', function() {
....
}
```

Comment: Why would that fix it? Are you suggesting the OP is using an old version of jQuery? OP wanted to use a delegated handler.

Comment: They won't work with .bind either. Event delegation is needed.